# How to SELECT with two CSV files/... on PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, csv, copy, r

I have two CSV files which you can insert into the following `PostgreSQL` schema.
However, I cannot `\COPY` the data into the tables. 
Pseudocode

1. Let `data_id=1`
2. Show name and `event_value` from *data.csv* and *log.csv*, respectively
3. Do this request from R with connection to PostgreSQL

Pseudocode in other words but not correct syntax

```
SELECT name, event_value 
    FROM data, log
    WHERE data_id=1;
```

### CSV files

I enclose the header in double quotes in CSV files (thread [PG COPY error: invalid input syntax for integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18297980/pg-copy-error-invalid-input-syntax-for-integer)). 
*data.csv* where two integer/SERIAL + integer

```
"data_id", "event_value"
1, 777
1, 666
2, 111
4, 123 
3, 324
1, 245
```

*log.csv* where integer/SERIAL + string so I put enclosed the latter one in double quotes

```
"data_id", "name"
1, "leo"
2, "leopold"
3, "lorem"
```

### PostgreSQL

Schema and workflow

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS data, log;    
CREATE TABLE data (
        data_id SERIAL NOT NULL, -- no primary key possible here, because possible have many events per data id
        event_value INTEGER NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE log (
        data_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        name INTEGER NOT NULL
);

-- https://stackoverflow.com/a/2987451/54964
-- https://soleil4716.wordpress.com/2010/08/19/using-copy-command-in-postgresql/
-- joanolo, HEADER
\COPY data FROM '/home/masi/Data/data.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
\COPY log FROM '/home/masi/Data/log.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

Work flow pseudocode

1. Start from clean table (drop old tables) and Create new tables
2. Insert two CSV files into the tables
3. Do SELECT now with connection to PostgreSQL from R

Output

```
masi@masi:~$ psql -f schema.sql 
psql:schema.sql:1: NOTICE:  table "data" does not exist, skipping
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
CREATE TABLE
COPY 6
psql:schema.sql:14: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: " leo"
CONTEXT:  COPY log, line 2, column name: " leo"
```

I should not have mistakes in CSV files, based on the thread [PG COPY error: invalid input syntax for integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18298348/54964).

OS: Linux Debian 8.7
PostgreSQL: 9.4
Related: `R sqldf`/... approach in the thread [How to select on CSV files by R sqldf/data.table/dplyr?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/363576/16920)

Comment: If your CSV files have a `HEADER` you want to specify the `HEADER true` option in your `COPY` statement. See [`COPY` documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html)

Comment: @joanolo Please, see the body. I can use only `HEADER`, since `HEADER true` does not wark in `\COPY`. - - The original error still persists in the case.

Answer (score 1):

Error is obvious since you're intending to add characters to integer defined column. Just change datatype for name column in log table from integer to varchar(10)

Answer (score 0):

The wanted SELECT can be done as

```
-- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364970/16920
SELECT a.event_value, b.name
    FROM data a, log b
    WHERE a.data_id = 1
      AND a.data_id=b.data_id;
```